# How can I get service-name and function-name from serverless.yml in my Lambda NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, serverless

```
service: serverless-demo-app        
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs10.x

functions:
  sample1:
    handler: sample1/handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: sample1
          method: get
  sample2:
    handler: sample2/handler
    events:
      - http:
          path: sample2
          method: get
```

When I am invoking sample2 from sample1, I need it's full name, like: `serverless-demo-app-dev-sample2`

So, how can I get service name, function name and environment name inside function1?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

> ${self:service}

..to obtain the service name.

AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME, will show your functions.